# How to replace one child react/html component with another based up on event using react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to react and I have a react component structure like:

```
<MainComponent>
     <Button />
     <Content />
</MainComponent>
```

Now when I click on the **Button**, I need to replace the existing *div* (say div1) of the **Content** component with another *div* (div2). Can you please tell me how to do it. Thank you.

Note: Till now, on click event I have been changing the data of the single div using state and prop. Now I got to replace the whole div with another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

```js
render() {
  var returnIt;
  if (useDivOne) returnIt = (<div id='one'></div>);
  else returnIt = (<div id='two'></div>);
  return (returnItj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, Can you tell me whether this is the proper way in case of very huge code replacement? Or is there any way to maintain them as two separate single pages. I mean is there any concept in react to handle SPA?

Comment: SPA is very natural with React. I am not sure what you mean by very huge code replacement? You could look at the patterns at https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns. React.14/ReFluxPages may give a hint as to how to organize a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your structure:

```
<MainComponent>
  <Button />
  <Content />
</MainComponent>
```

and Content renders something like:

```
<div>
  this is div 1
</div>
```

I would think you would need to pass a prop to Content that would tell you which div to render, then in Content's Render you manipulate the properties of Boolean logic to present a different component:

```
class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      {
        !this.props.RenderDiv2Bool &&
        <div>
          This is Div1 and it will be rendered
          because RednerDiv2Bool is false.
        </div>
      }
      {
        this.props.renderDiv2Bool &&
        <div>
          This is Div2 and it will be rendered
          because RednerDiv2Bool is true.
        </div>
      }
    )
  };
}
```

Not necessarily better but just another way to do it.